# Passing multiple separate strings to function

Tags: c

i have several strings that i am trying to pass into a function for processing. the function paramenters must stay the same. I would think looping over the strings, and calling the function would be the way to go but im not sure how to pass several different named strings into a function. This is what im starting with

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char s[], int counts[]);

int main(void)
{
     int aray[2];
     char text0[] = "This is one of Several strings2use.";
     char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
     char text2[] = "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)";
     """ how do i pass each string one by one into the function? im not trying to
         call the function 3 separate times for each string"""
}

void convert(char s[], int counts[])
{
    """this function grabs each string and processes it to find word counts and
    character counts. does not return anything and accepts one string at a time"""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the sample code using variable arguments.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sample (int num, char *p, ... )
{
 va_list arguments;                     
 char * temp;
 int x = 0;

 /* Initializing arguments to store all values after num */
 va_start ( arguments, num );  
 printf ("Num of addr[%d]\n", num);
 printf ("[%p] ", p);
 for ( ; x < num-1; x++ )        
 {
     temp = va_arg ( arguments, char* ); 
 printf ("[%p] ", temp);
 }
 va_end ( arguments );                
 printf ("\n");        
}

int main()
{
  char *test[5]= {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"};
  printf( "[%p] [%p] [%p] [%p] [%p]\n",test[0],test[1],test[2],test[3],test[4]);
  sample (sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]), test[0],test[1],test[2],test[3],test[4] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple arguments to a function you can refer `printf` function syntax. But the more easy way to meet you requirement is, use array of pointer. Find the below example for more information.

```
void sample (int num, unsigned char **p)
{
printf (" \n %d %s %s %s %s %s \n",num, p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4]);
}

main(void)   
{

  unsigned char *Test [5] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"};
  sample (sizeof (Test)/sizeof(Test [0]),  Test);
}
```

Comment: do you hapen to know the syntax for printf. i cant use pointers. so what your suggesting is something like 'printf("%function % function % function", function[text0],function[text1], function[text2])' if thats allowed im just going to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

here , as suggested above you can use function with variable arguments as well as a n x m 2-D array , where n and m are respective rows and columns and then you can simply pass that array to a function .. but in case you have different arrays you should go with the variable number of arguments in function. please get some basic idea of c variable arguments before implementing them into your function. following link would be useful for creating of function .

### http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm